# Problem in clicking button all over it. CSS button

Tags: html, css, button, click

**Probem** 
I have a CSS button which am able to click only on the test area.
I am unable to click on the non-text area of the button.

Here is the HTML code for the "EDIT" button on my website.

```
<div class="stndrd_btn">
    <p><?php echo $html->link('Edit','... destination....'); ?></p>
</div>
```

Below is the CSS code for the button.

```
.stndrd_btn {
    width:140px;
    height:30px;
    background:url(img/stndrd_btn.png);
    color:#FFF;
    cursor: pointer;

}

.stndrd_btn p {
    color:#FFF;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-top:6px;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Please let me know how i can make the clicking work all over the button. THANKS!!

Comment: Works fine on Chrome. What browser are you having problems on?

Answer (score 6):

Make the `<a>` tag `display: block` and give it a width and height, so that the button fully consists of the `<a>` element.

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" style="display: block; width: 300px; height: 200px; background: gold;">Go to Google</a>
```

Alternatively, you can give it a border so that the text is in the middle of the button:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" style="display: block; width: 300px; border: solid gold 100px; background: gold;">Go to Google</a>
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend inline styles

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the `p` tag is inside the `div` but you apply the background image to the `div` but the link in the `p`. The `p` also has padding.

So in a nutshell try do it all in the one tag.

EDIT: like @Sjoerd says: use the `a` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need the p tag. Apply everything to the div and I think you should be ok. I would really apply the click to an  href though then you can also have a fallback if nesseccary for people without JS or search engines.

```
<div class="stndrd_btn">
    <a href="#"><?php echo $html->link('Edit','... destination....'); ?></a>
</div>
```

In this case apply the button properties to the a tag.

Answer (score 0):

make the **<a> as **display:block** and give it padding as something like**

padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;

this will increase the click area of a link

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "a href" tag only and then add padding and background to it. padding: 5px 5px; background:grey; This will look like a button and will be clickable.